# Horizontal Scroll on hover / on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First of all thanks in advance for any help.

**Case:**
I have multiple divs in one line. These divs are in a box and I'm able to scroll horizontally in this box to see the other divs.
I've made two buttons (L for left and R for right) to scroll horizontally when hovering or clicking these buttons.

**Problem:**
I've already tried with some CSS and JavaScript but I can't seem to get this right.

Does anybody know how to achieve horizontal scroll when hovering / clicking on a button (or arrow)?

I've made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wsemLhtz/

Would be awesome to get this working with CSS only or simple JavaScript since I have to implement this into a Joomla system. I know there are some jQuery plug-ins out there but in Joomla I have to replace all $-tags with "jQuery" and it's quite annoying to do this in every file.

Best regards.

```css
.box-outer {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 6rem;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 0rem;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.arrow-right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 10rem;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box-inner {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 6rem;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.thumb {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-outer">
  <a class="arrow-left">L</a>
  <a class="arrow-right">R</a>
  <div class="box-inner">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what you are already tried?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use that)

```js
var box = $(".box-inner"), x;
$(".arrow").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("arrow-right")) {
    x = ((box.width() / 2)) + box.scrollLeft();
    box.animate({
      scrollLeft: x,
    })
  } else {
    x = ((box.width() / 2)) - box.scrollLeft();
    box.animate({
      scrollLeft: -x,
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.box-outer {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 6rem;
  position: relative;
}
.arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 0rem;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.arrow-right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 10rem;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box-inner {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 6rem;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.thumb {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-outer">
  <a class="arrow-left arrow">L</a>
  <a class="arrow-right arrow">R</a>
  <div class="box-inner">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/wsemLhtz/6/)

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tbe64uzL/5/):**

```
$('a').click(function() {    
  switch ($(this).text()) {
  case "L":
    $('.box-inner').scrollLeft(-300);
    break;

  case "R":
    $('.box-inner').scrollLeft(300);
    break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery like following........

```
 $(".arrow-left").click(function () { 
   var leftPos = $('.box-inner').scrollLeft();
   $(".box-inner").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 50}, 1);
 });

 $(".arrow-right").click(function () { 
     var leftPos = $('.box-inner').scrollLeft();
     $(".box-inner").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 50}, 1);
  });
```

EDIT: Here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wsemLhtz/5/

Answer (score -2):

There you go ! Solution here using some simple Jquery :)

http://codepen.io/AxelCardinaels/pen/rxMrem

HTML :

```
<div class="box-outer">
  <a class="arrow-left">L</a>
  <a class="arrow-right">R</a>
  <div class="box-inner">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.box-outer {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 6rem;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 0rem;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.arrow-right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 10rem;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box-inner {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 6rem;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.thumb {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JS :

```
$(".arrow-left").click(function(){
     // To get actual position
    var actualScroll = $(".box-inner").scrollLeft();
  // To set new position
  $(".box-inner").scrollLeft(actualScroll+50)
})
```

Hope this is what you were looking for !